# XHR no longer available with jQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
$.ajax(options)
    .then(function (response) {
        // success
    }, function (response, a, b) {
        // fail
    })
    .always(function (output, status, xhr) {
        // xhr is always null here
    });
```

Previously, `xhr` was available. How can I access it with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: what version of jquery you are using?

Comment: @DeyvisonSouto 3.2.0

Comment: Do you use the ".then" setup for anything? I think the signature for the callbacks are different when using .then compared to using the old school $.ajax call.

Comment: Why are you not using `$.ajax().done().fail().always()`

Comment: We're going to need more information. At the moment we don't have enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement like following with `jquery 3.2`. Some of previous ajax methods are deprecated with new version of jquery.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "yourUrl" )
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function(xhr, status,output ) {
      console.log(xhr);
  });
```